# Placing boost socket into std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I was thinking that this would be straight forward but I must be missing something crucial, hence the error =O.
I'm receiving the 'use of deleted function' error inside my source file.

Anyhow, I know my header file is correctly hooked up as it's been called properly throughout the source file, besides this line and the source code snippet is the only place that should require evaluation.

**Header source code**

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
std::map<std::string, tcp::socket> mSockets;
```

**Source file code**

```
tcp::socket socket(ioService);
mAcceptor.accept(socket);
std::string myKey = "Socket"; // Didn't add actual key string creation
mSockets[myKey] = socket;
```

**Error**

error: Use of delete function 'boost::asio::basic_stream_socket& boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::operator{const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket&)' 
mSockets[myKey] = socket;

Goes on to say:
Is implicitly declared as deleted because 'boost::asio::basic_stream_socket' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator class basic_stream_socket.

**Update**

@Radosław Cybulski suggested to try std::move(socket) and this eliminated a good portion of the error but this now results in.

**Error #2**

'boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::basic_stream_socket()' second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(_tuple2))...)

Comment: Don't add more questions to an answered question. Create a new question.

Comment: This is strange. I can't imagine code where single object manages directly multiple sockets. In my code, single socket is wrapped by some class which handles socket logic and only that object is aggregated by something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `map` with `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` as value, because `map` requires its value to be default constructible (for example default constructed instance is created when `map::operator[]` is called), `asio::ip::tcp::socket` doesn't fulfill it because its ctor reqiures at least to take `io_context` object as argument.

Use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` as value of map.

Comment: This makes sense. I've seen someone use a vector with shared_ptr. Thank you for the reconfirmation!

Comment: it''s not `std::map` that requires the contained value type to be default constructible. It's `operator[]( const Key& key );`, so `emplace` and `operator[]( Key&& key )` works with types without a default constructor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `operator[]` for move semantics doesn't work - [demo on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5bsvRV). But in general you are right, only `operator[]` requires the mapped value to be default constructible, not all members of `map`. Maybe I generalized my answer too much, but when I use some container I want all its members to be *enabled*, and not to do some tricks like `emplace` to insert new value.

Comment: @rafix07 You're right, it doesn't work with the default allocator and I haven't tried making my own. Looks scary :-) However, `emplace` seems just fine to me.

Comment: A work around is checking if the key exists in the map first, and if it doesn't, push the one you want in. No default constructor that way.  It worked for me, at least in a similar problem I was having.

Comment: @Chipster `std::map` doesn't have `push`. Don't you mean `insert` or any of the `emplace` functions with `std::move`? `try_emplace` perhaps?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, I'm sorry. I mean insert. Thank you, good catch.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
mSockets.insert({ myKey, std::move(socket) });
```

Copy operator is deleted, because there's no good way to copy socket. I mean, you connect to something, then copy and what now? You can send on both copies, only one (which one?), something else? So it's deleted and if  you want to pass it around, use move constructor / assignment and `std::move`.

EDIT: since empty constructor is also deleted, you can't use `mSockets[key] = ...`. So we've to rely on `insert` / `emplace`. Why? `operator[]` on map requires existence of default constructor of value type. I've no idea, why, but here is it.

Comment: This solved half the problem, the newest error says "no matching function for call to 'boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_stream_socket()' second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(_tuple2))...).
Thank you for the suggestion, maybe were missing just one more component.

Comment: @KyleJ If your question has been answered, accept the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It has not.

Comment: Gimme a second. Fixed.

Comment: problem here is `operator[]` which by default inserts a value with default constructor. Since `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` doesn't have it there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The socket can't be default constructed and the operator you are using requires it to be just that (when the default allocator is used).

[T& std::map::operator[](const Key& key)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> *[...]* `value_type` must be [EmplaceConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/EmplaceConstructible) from
>   `std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(key), std::tuple<>()`. When the default allocator is used, this means that
>   `key_type` must be
>   [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible)
>   and `mapped_type` must be
>   **[DefaultConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible)**.

You can however use `emplace()` and move the socket into the `std::pair<std::string, tcp::socket>` that's being emplace constructed:

`auto [it, inserted] = mSockets.emplace(myKey, std::move(socket));`

This will [move-construct](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload9.html) the socket using the constructor `tcp::socket(tcp::socket&&)` instead of `tcp::socket()` (which doesn't exist as you've noticed).